# Lightning component Service Console, get and edit content of Quick Action Email Message

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, aura, emailmessage, helper

im trying to develop one Lightning Component for Service Console who is in charge of GET\EDIT entire\parts of Email in Case Management Quick Actions (screenshot) when the user click on the button of this component.

For example: i want replace "Content 1" (see screenshot) to another string by click on the button of my component

I have try to import jquery and make some test, but nothing of positive.

Anyone has one method for get the Email Message by some api or something simile?

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: If this is for Console, you'll likely need to reference the Lightning Console JS API. See the Console docs for more.

Comment: Thank you for this tip, but unfortunatly i dont find nothing about this :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to understand how the Console works. You'll want to refer to the [Salesforce Console Guide - Lightning Experience API Section](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_js_getting_started.htm). There are a number of methods you're going to need to become familiar with. First, your component will need to know what record tab is in context using a combination of `getEnclosingTabId()` followed by `getTabInfo(tabId)`, which includes the object ID in the response payload.

For `getEnclosingTabId()`, if the calling component is within a subtab, then the subtab ID is returned. If the calling component is within a workspace tab, then the workspace ID is returned. Finally, you'll want to know what, if any NavigationItem is Selected. The latter has a method called `getSelectedNavigationItem()`. This should point you in the right direction. There are also a number of Events within the console you'll likely want to monitor in addition to what I've pointed you to.